# How to scale down a HD image to SD images?

Tags: java, javascript, css, image, image-processing

I'm a newbie here. I have searched up a little but couldn't find any solution.

I have a big image (HD Image) which I will ask the user to upload.

I want to show the image on Mobile/Tablet/Desktop.

**Question**:

Given a HD image, How do I scale down my image to 480p(mobile) or 720p(Tablet) or 1080p(desktop).

How can I reduce the size of the image?

Server side is fine too. Any java open source libraries available would really help!

Thanks,

R

Comment: Are you looking to scale down just the dimensions of the image to fit on screen or are you wanting to reduce the file size and create a low-res version of the image?

Comment: I want to scale down dimensions and size.. So that mobiles load smaller images than tablets or desktops :)

Comment: I think the most common and easy-to-use solutions for server-side Java image re-sizing is either [Thumbnailator](https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) or [Imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/).

Answer (score 0):

```
max-width:100%; height:auto; 
example: <img src="..." style="max-width:100%; height:auto;" >
```

I normally create css classes like that to scale images with different screen sizes and devices. You can also use "width" to fill whole content block. That is if you want to do it without changing/resizing image file itself.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript itself cannot compress file for you, therefor the size and resolution of the image that you serve will always be the source resolution.

I have actually just encountered this issue, and the solution was to user a Server-Side language such as PHP to do this for you. If you are interested I used [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

Comment: I want a Java Implementation for this .. yes, server side implementation is fine. @Eric E